# Creating Dynamic WCF service proxy .net 2.0 assemblies

Tags: .net, wcf

i have some WCF services either hosted in IIS or self-hosted in windows service.

Initially, the wcf services were hosted in IIS only and .net 2.0 assembles 
refering the services were working fine.

As these services hosted in local machine the url created while refering the 
service  was working fine even if the 
machine changes.

Now, the wcf services can be either self hosted or IIS and url will additionally 
have a port number also in the case of self hosting.

In the client aplication the Services are referenced as WebReference and reference property - UrlBehaviour has already been set to Dynamic, so that it will create proxy according to the 
endpoint url specified in configuration file, This settings is not working 
now,even though the endpoint url is changed in config file ,it is hitting the 
same old endpoint url that was created at the time of service reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way or another, make sure that the "Url" property of the proxy class is getting set to the value you want before you call the web method.

Comment: Url is not changing and it is taking url that was created at the time of service reference.                                         I think the only way to set the url is through the Configuration file and this is not working

Comment: I mean that when the URL is changed through the config, it is setting the Url property. You can do the same.